# Transform an inhomogeneous dirichlet problem into a homogeneous one? i.e. Burgers equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I need to transform an  inhomogeneous dirichlet problem into a homogeneous one. For exeample the burgers equation: 
$$\begin{cases} \partial_t u(x,t) + u(x,t) \partial_x u(x,t)=0\\ 
u(0,t)=0,& \forall t\in [0,1]\\ 
u(x,0)=g(x),&\forall x\in [0,1] \end{cases}
$$

So how can I transform this problem to something with zero boundaries?

Comment: Assuming that $g(0)=0$, you can look at $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+h(x,t)$ where $h(x,t)$ is a function that you choose for yourself with the property $h(x,0)=g(x)$ and $h(0,t)=0$. If $g(0) \neq 0$ then you must be more careful in handling the corner singularity.

Comment: That said, homogeneous *spatial* boundary data is usually desirable but homogeneous *temporal* boundary data (i.e. initial or final data) is typically not a problem for most methods of solution.

Comment: Regarding what the equation describes, I would be happy with $g$ having compact support and $g(0)=0$. 

But how to choose $h$? And then I would solve $\partial_t (v+h) + (v+h) \partial_x (v+h)=0$?

Comment: You pick $h$ to be "simple" so that the resulting inhomogeneous PDE for $v$ is not too difficult to solve. Unfortunately here the nonlinearity produces a difficulty because you cannot simply move all the terms involving $h$ to the other side as a forcing, since there are terms $h \partial_x v$ and $v \partial_x h$. But at least these terms are linear in $v$...

Comment: resulting inhomogeneous PDE? 
So my problem is, that I am in need of zero boundaries.

Comment: The PDE itself becomes inhomogeneous (due to the term $h \partial_x h$). The boundary data becomes homogeneous.

Comment: Okay, thx! So if $g(0)=0$ I could simply choose $h(x,t)=g(x)$ because that gives me $h(x,0)=g(x)$ and $h(0,t)=g(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that will work in this situation.

Comment: So what I get is $\partial_t v + (v+h) \partial_x(v+h) =0$ with $v(0,t)=v(x,0)=0$, right?

Comment: Since $\partial_t h = 0$, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thx! 
The whole purpose was applying Newton's method...


So I applied Newton's method and solved the linearized problem with finite differences, that's what i got with 3 iterations: http://prntscr.com/lrlyx7

I used $g= \sin((x+1.5* 1/10)*10*\pi)+1$.

Better discretization: http://prntscr.com/lrmcbs

Does that seem right to you?